# xmllint: how to extract children containing certain text to another xml

Tags: xml, bash, grep, xmllint

I have following xml as an example:

```
<Config>
<Version>0</Version>
<Model>My model</Model>
<ParameterList>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>Device.Modelname</Name>
        <Value>XC60</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>Device.Size</Name>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>Tyre.Size</Name>
        <Value>20</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>Tyre.Model</Name>
        <Value>WATSU</Value>
    </Parameter>
</ParameterList>
</Config>
```

Here is what I want to achieve as a new (separate) xml file. So, I want to extract some of the children with matching criteria to and create a new xml file containing only those children.

```
<Config>
<ParameterList>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>Device.Size</Name>
        <Value>4</Value>
    </Parameter>
    <Parameter>
        <Name>Tyre.Model</Name>
        <Value>WATSU</Value>
    </Parameter>
</ParameterList>
</Config>
```

The criteria is that, the Name of the child must be either Device.Size or Tyre.Model.

I tried looping through each child and grepping or xarg'ing in the values in a bash script but I was wondering if there is a simple way to achieve this in xmllint itself.

Comment: I'd suggest using xslt, build an identity transform (search SO, should be several hits) and then filter out all stuff you don't want by empty templates, e.g. matching `Version`, `Model` as well as the Parameters you don't want. xsltproc is another program below the libxml/xmllint suite.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). There is no need for manually parsing XML nowadays ;)

In addition xmllint offers a [XPath interface](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/extract-xml-elements-using-xmllint/#gs.nGd83eQ).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14317243)

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz IMO the core of the answer is the suggestion to use XPath, and it would work even without the links. They're just pointers to relevant docs.

Comment: The author "was wondering if there is a simple way to achieve this in xmllint itself" and I think XPath, especially using it with xmllint, is a appropriate answer to this question.